# How to delete back up files

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

I need to delete files with ".bak" and ".csv.bak" extensions. I use .net c#.

I tried like this:

```
        string srcDir = @"D:\Backup";

        string[] bakList = Directory.GetFiles(srcDir,".bak");

        if (Directory.Exists(srcDir))
        {
            foreach (string f in bakList)
            {
                File.Delete(f);
            }
        }
```

But when debugging, the bakList array is empty.

`Directory.GetFiles()` is not loading the file names in the array. I cant figure out what is wrong in my coding.

Comment: Change your filter to "*.bak" rather than ".bak".

Comment: @JayRiggs ya i did that... but then also those files are not deleted in the directory. My file is of the form "Data Logger[0].csv.bak", should i take as "*.csv.bak" or "*.bak"??

Comment: Do I need to create a source and a destination directory, so that i can copy from src to dest and delete the files from dest folder. is it mandatory??

Comment: To confirm: the only files you want to delete have file name patterns of 'Data Logger[0].csv.bak'? Also, when you try to run the code in Maryam's answer are you getting an exception? If so, what is the exception and on which line?

Comment: @JayRiggs I din get any exception.. I had backup files which was generated by a smart server.. so its back up files had number as extention, ex: "Data Logger[2].csv.bak.1"  I have posted the answer below..

Comment: Why you call exists after looking for files in that directory already? you just got yourself a race condition...

Answer (score 2):

You need to Add `*` before your `.bak` in `GetFiles()`

```
string srcDir = @"D:\Backup";
string[] bakList = Directory.GetFiles(srcDir,"*.bak");

if (Directory.Exists(srcDir))
{
    foreach (string f in bakList)
    {
        File.Delete(f);
    }
}
```

If you need to search for both types maybe it works better

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(srcDir, "*.*")
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".bak"));
```

Comment: Better to mention the change you made and also explain how that helps with your answer. The * is not easily distinguishable :)

Comment: @kousalyarajan I optimized the filter for `Directoty.GetFiles` , check it now.

Comment: @maryam arshi I changed that to "*.bak", but then also my directory files are not deleted.. my files are in the format.. "Data Logger[0].csv.bak".. should i take this as "*.csv.bak" or just "*.bak"

Comment: @kousalyarajan look into the new query

Comment: @maryam arshi still My files are not deleted... I'm not an administrator of the system.. I think this is only is the prob.. I need to change the security properties of the folder i think..

Comment: @MaryamArshi I found that the security reasons is not an issue.. because i can delete other type of files like .pptx,.docx, etc... but i cant delete ".bak"  i even mentioned the file name, then also that thing is not deleted...

Comment: @kousalyarajan Probably another program is using these files and maybe you just don't have permission to delete this kind of file , because I tried the code above in three different system and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If your file name is

"Data Logger[2].csv.bak", 
go to the properties and check the type of file. it will be something like this

"1 File (.1)" .The file has number as its end extension. So i used like this.

string[] bk = Directory.GetFiles(srcDir, "****.bak.****");

foreach (string f in bk)
            {
                File.Delete(f);
            }

its working...